# Generate 100 rows with random data using SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I use this SQL query to insert 1 row of data:

```
INSERT INTO public.tasks (id, business_name, meta_title, status, title, type) VALUES (
    '10'::bigint, 'business name 1'::character varying, 'meta title 1'::character varying, 'active'::character varying, 'title 1'::character varying, 'merchant'::character varying)
    returning id;
```

Is it possible with 1 SQL query to insert 100 rows with random data into Postgre table?

Comment: What do you mean by random data?

Comment: random characters of data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,100) AS id, 
md5(random()::text) AS business_name, 
md5(random()::text) AS meta_title,
md5(random()::text) AS status,
md5(random()::text) AS title,
md5(random()::text) AS type
```

Comment: For Date field how I can generate random date?

Comment: You can do different things with `random()` function and dates. I.e. if you want random day from the last year, you can do something like this: `select date(now() - floor(random()  * 365) * '1 day'::interval)`